# Why can i not use properties in a strongly-typed hubs?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core

Let's have a strongly-typed hub like this:

```
public class TestHub : Hub<IClient>
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Clients.Caller.UserPriority = 1;
    }
}
```

And IClient is the following:

```
public interface IClient
{
    int UserPriority { get; set; }
}
```

When I'am trying to call DoSomething, i got the following error:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The interface 'IClient' m
ust not contain any properties.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder`1.VerifyInterface(Typ
e interfaceType)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder`1.GenerateClientBuild
er()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder`1.<>c.<.cctor>b__12_0
()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.TypedClientBuilder`1.Build(IClientProxy
proxy)
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hubs.TypedHubCallerConnectionContext`1.get_Ca
ller()
```

But when I create a non-strongly-typed hub, I can do the following without error (with using dynamic property):

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Clients.Caller.UserPriority = 1;
    }
}
```

I dont understand this behavior. Why can I not set a property to a client in a strongly-typed Hub?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Could be a bug, still all in beta. If you feel it's a bug you should open an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/issues

Comment: Reported but nobody answers...